# Sabre : how can we add 'title' with passenger name in sabre API

Tags: sabre

I am using passengerDetailsRQ sabre API to create PNR and save passenger info. But as per my observation they have option to add first-name and last-name while i want to add title as well. So please suggest if anyone have any suggestion

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

The Tile goes on the first-name field, after that, add a space then the title

Please check the Format Finder reference below, which has all that you need to know on how to add titles, and character limitation.
https://formatfinder.sabre.com/Content/PassengerNameRecordPNR/PassengerNameRecordFields/NameFieldInPNR.aspx?ItemID=face5f8246b6423794920175b4cc2a3c

In order to login, you may use the same credentials used for creating session on web services.

Comment: Thanks Wisdoom, but in this way in the issued ticket we can see name as last-name/title first-name while it should be last-name/first-name title

Comment: That is the only way to add titles in Sabre. Even if that is printed in the ticket airlines know that is the title. If you are still having doubts I recommend you to contact Product Support that are the specialists on Sabre host and they will be able to clarify all this.

Comment: In case you don't know the phone number, log into Agency eServices, I believe the direct link would be: https://agencyeservices.sabre.com/Support/Sabre-Support.aspx